# Element disappears after removing class

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I've come across some strange behavior in Chrome 60.0 when removing a class from an element with a very specific configuration.

I removed the `fade` class from an `<h1>` element and it makes it completely disappear. The problem can be reproduced by removing the class in the dev-tools element inspector as well. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

The element should just go back to full opacity after clicking the button.

[image]

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   h1.classList.remove('fade');
});
```

```css
.center {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fade {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div>
    <h1 class="fade">Watch me disappear</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: not able to replicate. Even this snippet seems to work fine

Comment: Yeah, this happens in Chrome 60 alright ...

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 59 Mac.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` causes that issue

Comment: Do you need the `overflow: hidden` on the `h1` element? If you remive this then it will work.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or something? Because, if you are using bootstrap, it has its own class `fade`. So that may be the one creating the issue.

Comment: will work if its an h2 etc:)

Comment: @bhv Yes, changing just about *anything* in the html or css keeps it from happening. I'm just curious as to why.

Comment: @spencer.sm maybe a bug. But using `float: left` and `overflow: hidden` in combination on the same element seems to be strange anyway.

Comment: yes it seems like bug, reported

Comment: was fine with chrome 59 but happened to me too after upgrade to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the overflow: hidden property defined for h1, will solve your problem.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  h1.classList.remove('fade');
});
```

```css
.center {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    float: left;
}

.fade {
    opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div>
    <h1 class="fade">Watch me disappear</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Changing just about *anything* in the html or css keeps it from happening. I'm curious as to why.

Comment: @spencer.sm why do you need the overflow: hidden; property for h1 element?

The property  overflow: hidden; should be use for the containers like <div> and <span> not for the elements like <h1> or <p>.

Comment: I don't "need it" for the the h1 element. This isn't the exact code that I'm having a problem with in the application I'm developing. It is a simplified example that still reproduces the problem. In fact in the actual code, the element with a problem *is* a div. And it needs the overflow hidden because it contains child elements that that are floating to the left and right. I added the overflow hidden because I wanted the outer div to encompass the inner divs without changing the display to be inline-block.